GCP Cloud Run complains "can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
I have my project wrapped up as docker containers. Please see the  Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "main.py"]

And below is my ci.yml file
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  dependencies:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          cache: pip
          python-version: "3.12"
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt

  deploy:
    needs: [dependencies]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: |
      github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch' || (github.event_name == 'push' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/main')
    env:
      DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Google Cloud SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1
        with:
          project_id: service-a-123456
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_AUTHENTICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON }}
          export_default_credentials: true  

      - name: Authenticate with Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_AUTHENTICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON }}    

      - name: Authorize Docker push
        run: gcloud auth configure-docker us-west1-docker.pkg.dev
        

      # Docker runtime image
      - name: Build Runtime with Cache
        id: build-runtime-with-cache
        continue-on-error: true
        run: >-
          docker build
          --build-arg COLLECT_STATIC=1
          --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1
          -f Dockerfile
          --cache-from ${{ secrets.RUNTIME_DOCKERIMAGE_URL }}:latest
          -t ${{ secrets.RUNTIME_DOCKERIMAGE_URL }}:${{ github.sha }}
          -t ${{ secrets.RUNTIME_DOCKERIMAGE_URL }}:latest
          .

      - name: Build Runtime with Cache failed -> Build Runtime without Cache
        if: ${{ steps.build-runtime-with-cache.outcome == 'failure' }}
        run: >-
          docker build
          --build-arg COLLECT_STATIC=1
          -f Dockerfile
          -t ${{ secrets.RUNTIME_DOCKERIMAGE_URL }}:${{ github.sha }}
          -t ${{ secrets.RUNTIME_DOCKERIMAGE_URL }}:latest
          .

      - name: Push runtime image to Artifact Registry
        run: docker push --all-tags ${{ secrets.RUNTIME_DOCKERIMAGE_URL }}

      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v1
        with:
          service: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_NAME }}
          image: ${{ secrets.RUNTIME_DOCKERIMAGE_URL }}:${{ github.sha }}
          region: us-west1

Now, when I tried to deploy the container to GCP cloud run. First step push to artifact succeeded. However, when it was deployed to the cloud run, I got errors in the GCP logs:
{
  httpRequest: null
  insertId: "78475d0e111149z00b7b87cc"
  jsonPayload: null
  labels: {3}
  logName: "projects/service-a-123456/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"
  operation: null
  payload: "textPayload"
  protoPayload: null
  receiveLocation: "us-west1"
  receiveTimestamp: "2024-11-14T19:25:19.018800003Z"
  resource: {2}
  severity: "DEFAULT"
  sourceLocation: null
  split: null
  textPayload: "python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
  timestamp: "2024-11-14T19:25:19.014505Z"
  traceSampled: false
}

As you can see, it clearly said python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
I then checked on my local docker by booting the containers with the docker desktop and in the service-a container, I can see the /app/main.py there.

Please help. Thanks.
UPDATE: I downloaded the uploaded image and run on my local. And the current folder is "/", under it there is a app folder, which has Dockerfile and main.py. Still don't know why it's failed.

You have to start the path / to correspond with the root level and locate it in the folder app where you got the script for main.py. Change the config file as follows:
CMD ["python",  "app/main.py"]

OR
CMD ["python", "./app/main.py"]

Hope it helps!

thanks for replying. Unfortunately, I tried your propose and it didn't solve the issue. The log shows "python: can't open file '/app/./app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" error.

Try to explicitly copy main.py to the right location:
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel 
&& pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY main.py /app/  # Explicitly copy main.py to /app

CMD ["python", "main.py"]


COPY main.py /app/
instead of
COPY . .

I following your approach, copy main.py to /app/ explicitly. And I got the same error "python: can't open file '/app/main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory". Thanks all the same.

@Laodao, I appreciate your patience in following the workaround I provided. I found this answer by @jkr to this stackoverflow post, where they addressed finding the directory structure of main.py.

KikoZam, thanks again for helping here. I really appreciate it. However, what the post said is basically what I previously did to get the screenshot in my post (it's just they use command to get into the container, but I directly go through the docker desktop). So the main.py is located at the /app/main.py. The docker-compose up is working at my local. It's just when I tried to deploy to GCP cloud run, I got that error in the logs.

Thank you for the information you’ve provided. I’m glad to share some thoughts to address your problem, and I hope this solution works this time.

If you’re using a .dockerignore file, double-check that it's not excluding main.py or the directory containing it.
Common .dockerignore mistakes:
*.pyc
__pycache__
.git
main.py  # Ensure this is not excluded


Install dependencies with no caching (to reduce image sizes and avoids stale dependencies) and update copy application files to Dockerfile.
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/

# Install dependencies with no caching
RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy application files
COPY . /app


CMD ["python", "/app/main.py"] # Explicitly run the main script



By doing this, verify the location of main.py. It must be present in the build context and not excluded by .dockerignore.
Thank  you.

Thanks, @KikoZam. However, this still not working. But I just figured out the solution, which is change the workdirectory from /app to /workspace. I know this doesn't make too much sense. However, it works for me. I want to thank you for keeping trying to help me here. Really appreciate it.

For the folks who might get the same issue, I find a way it works, though I don't know why. I change the work directory from /app to /workspace and it magically worked. Below is the Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim

# Create and set working directory explicitly
RUN mkdir -p /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

# Add debugging to see where we are and what files exist
RUN pwd && \
    ls -la && \
    echo "Current working directory contains:"

CMD ["python", "main.py"]

